# VF Page not retrieving to the original state after Page refresh

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, rerender, viewstate

I have a VF page that gets disabled with the click of a button. I want the **button 1** it to get enabled back after doing the refresh (browser refresh).
Below is my VF page and its controller:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="true" lightningStylesheets="false" showHeader="true" controller="MyController" >
   <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Question?">
         <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!debug}" />
         <br/>
         <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Button 1" id="btn1" action="{!display}" disabled="{!disable}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
    public class MyController {
    public boolean debug { public get; public set; }
    public boolean show {public get; public set;}
    public boolean disable { public get; public set;}
    public MyController(){
        debug = false;
        show = false;
        disable = false;
    }
    public void display(){
        show = true;
        disable = true;
    }
}
```

[image: This is how the page looks after clicking the button and after clicking the refresh button(button1 is disabled)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are refreshing a page from the browser, it sends the same form data to submit. The viewstate of the page is also sent. That's why you preserve this button disabled.

You can use `rerender` attribute of the `apex:commandButton` and specify id of the parent form to exclude resubmitting form with a viewstate:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="true" lightningStylesheets="false" showHeader="true" controller="MyController" >
   <apex:form id="form">
      <apex:pageBlock title="Question?">
         <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!debug}" />
         <br/>
         <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Button 1" id="btn1" action="{!display}" disabled="{!disable}" rerender="form"/>
         </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```